# Adding controls to Jquery Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add controls to a simple jquery carousel however I am not sure of how to do that. I have tried several other tutorials but I didn't really understand their method.
This is what I have

```
<div id='carousel_container'>
   <div id='carousel'>
     <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'/></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEozDag41Q5mhuWD45Bbq-9QaNU66CrokuWBd_oBjQ4n8wn70jkA'/></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'/></a></li>
       </ul>
      <div id='controls'>
       <!--left button-->
       <a href='#' id='prev'>prev</a>
        <a href='#' id='next'>next</a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
    $(this).find('li:last').after($(this).find('li:first'));
    $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    })
  },5000);


      $('#next').click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
         $(this).find('li:last').after($(this).find('li:first'));
         $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:480},1000,function(){
         $(this).find('li:last').after($(this).find('li:first'));
         $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    });
    return false;
  });

});

#carousel{
  width:480px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel ul{
  width:1920px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#carousel ul li{
  width:480px;
  text-align:center;
  height:280px;
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amosangyongjian/4jan3t10/2/

Hope someone can help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `prev` link functionality is incorrect. Replace following code with your `prev` jQuery code :

```
$('#prev').click(function() {
            $('#carousel ul').animate({
                marginLeft : 480
            }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).find('li:first').before($(this).find('li:last'));
                $(this).css({
                    marginLeft : 0
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your next and previous button code as follows. it will work. This script won't necessary when you use bootstrap as in the first answer.

```
$('#prev').click(function () {
    $('#carousel ul').find('li:first').before($('#carousel ul').find('li:last'));
});

$('#next').click(function () {
    $('#carousel ul').find('li:last').after($('#carousel ul').find('li:first'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code for carousel :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.carousel-inner>.item>img,.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
 width: 70%;
 margin: auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
 <br>
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active">
    <a href='#'><img
     src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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' /></a>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
    <a href='#'><img
     src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEozDag41Q5mhuWD45Bbq-9QaNU66CrokuWBd_oBjQ4n8wn70jkA' /></a>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
    <a href='#'><img
     src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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' /></a>
   </div>


  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"
   data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
   aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"
   data-slide="next"> <span
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

For any queries let me know

Comment: Is this tied to bootstrap? Is there a version that can integrate with my jquery stuff? Thanks for answering!

Comment: This is tied with bootstrap.Next and Previous functionality already implemented in bootstrap so no need to implement it separately.

Comment: If you want to do some extra functionality on prev/next click you use jquery on('click',function(){ }) to do it. Is this solved your doubt

Comment: The bootstrap one causes a bug in my site for some reason. That is why I chose to do the jquery focused one.

Comment: What bug? Post a new question. I will try if from my side to solve it

Comment: I don't have access to the entire code. Sorry. This is why Im trying to use the jquery options.

Comment: You can use this tutorial for jQuery corousel : http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery

Comment: I've managed to add a control for next. However my previous isn't working. Could you take a look at it? I've added an edit to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122495/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-jianya).